# push notification : both didFailToRegister and didRegister delegate not calling

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, apple-push-notifications

I am creating an application which support push notification
I am following all the steps.

It give error on simulator

```
Failed to get token, error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3010 "remote notifications are not supported in the simulator" UserInfo=0x5813d20 {NSLocalizedDescription=remote notifications are not supported in the simulator}
```

But on device it not calling the delegates methods

```
didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError  
didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken
```

My Code :

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound)];

    NSLog(@"application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions");
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{
    NSLog(@"My Token is %@",deviceToken);
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}

-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    NSLog(@"Received Notification %@", userInfo);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved for me:

In **Device**, go to:

```
`Settings->Notifications->YourApp->Enable_Notifications`
```

Answer (score 6):

`Push notification` won't work in `iPhone's Simulator`.

Try to check with device.

Answer (score 0):

As said by @kalyan Push Notification will NOT work in Simulator
But if you want to get ride of the warning here is the code to work 
with both Simulator and device (Check for **TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR** ) 
and iOS7 and iOS8 ( Check for **registerUserNotificationSettings** )

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    #if !TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
         // New User Notification Settings for iOS8 support
        if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {
            UIUserNotificationType types = UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert;
            UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                                                                     categories:nil];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
        } else { // for iOS 7
            UIRemoteNotificationType remoteNotificationType = UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
             remoteNotificationType];
        }

    #endif
}
```